# Separate multiple search values with an OR clause with Splunk?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard

I have a text box in a Splunk dashboard, and I'm trying to find out how I can separate values entered into the text box that are separated by commas with an OR clause.

For example:

values entered into text box: `102.99.99, 103.99.93, 203.23.21`

```
index=abc sourcetype=abc src_ip="$ip$"
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using the [`IN` operator](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/Search#Multiple_field-value_comparisons_with_the_IN_operator)?

```
index=abc sourcetype=abc src_ip IN ($ip$)
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I tried to make it more difficult than it had to be.